# NodeJS variable substitution for table in sql query

Tags: sql, node.js

I have a generic API call that I want to use across different tables in my DB.  This is the SQL query

```sql
SELECT * FROM $column_name WHERE step != Failed
```

I want to do this avoiding the possibility of sql injection by doing something like this

```js
var type = req.params.type;
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM ? WHERE step != FALSE';
postgres.client.query(sql, [ type ], function(err, results) {}
```

This doesn't work, and throws a syntax error.  I did some poking around and tried doing $1, and ??, instead of ? but nothing worked.  I did verify that the type variable is the proper value.

When I run this,

```js
var type = req.params.type;
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + type + ' WHERE step != FALSE';
postgres.client.query(sql, [ type ], function(err, results)
```

It works fine.  What's the deal here??

Comment: which module You use for postgres connection? since `?` substitution I saw in mysql module.

Comment: @num8er using 'pg'.  I've also tried using $1 which works for my other INSERT INTO queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand You use [node-postgres](https://node-postgres.com/) (alias: `pg`) module.

And for that module there is no `?` or `??` substitution.

You've to use `$N` notation, but pg driver does not allow dynamic table names.

So here's workaround:

1) create `constants/tableNames.js` file that will contain list of allowed table names to be used:

```
module.exports = [
  'users',
  'profiles', 
  ... and etc tables that You have
];
```

2) create `db/queries/selectFromTable.js` with following content that will be responsible for query generation with checking table name in allowed table names:

```
const tableNames = require('../../constants/tableNames.js');
module.exports = (tableName, queryTail = 'WHERE step != FALSE') => {
  if (tableNames.includes(tableName)) {
    return 'SELECT * FROM '+tableName+' '+queryTail; 
  }
  return 'SELECT NULL';
};
```

3) and use it in Your code as in example:

```
const selectFrom = require('db/queries/selectFromTable.js');

app.get('/records/:table', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const table = req.params.table;
    const query = selectFrom(table); 
    const result = await postgres.client.query(query, []);
    res.status(200).send(result.rows);

    /**
     * OR:
     * const table = req.params.table;
     * const something = req.query.something;
     * const query = selectFrom(table, 'WHERE step != FALSE AND something = $1::text');
     * const result = await postgres.client.query(query, [something]);
     * res.status(200).send(result.rows);
     */
  }
  catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: `api.get('/returnActive/:type', function(req, res) { 
 var type = req.params.type;
 var sql = 'SELECT * FROM $1 WHERE step != FALSE';
 postgres.client.query(sql,[type], function(err, results) {}
`

Results in 'Syntax error at or near $1'

Comment: @pcort since pg does not allow dynamic table name substitution only way is just concatenation. And to secure Yourself You can have table  names listings that You want to allow to use. Check my example.